# Growing fruit at a higher hardiness zone

Tags: hardiness-zone, gooseberries

I understand that growing fruit trees in a hardiness zone that's lower than recommended has a chance of your tree dying from frost damage.

However, what is the effect of growing fruit trees at higher hardiness zones than recommended? What happens to the tree and the fruit?

Today, I just bought a Hinnomaki Red Goosberry from the local nursery.

[image: Gooseberries in fruiting phase]

At the store, they claimed it was the correct zone range for our northern California town. However, when I went home to do more research, [Starkbros](https://www.starkbros.com/products/berry-plants/gooseberry-plants/hinnonmaki-red-gooseberry) says my zone is higher than the recommended range.

[image]

Comment: It's an interesting question in general.  In particular for gooseberries, I doubt it makes any difference.  Gooseberries are easier to succeed with than anything else I've every grown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might happen is no or very poor fruit production - many fruiting plants need a cold spell to trigger fruiting later on, so growing them in higher zones where it doesn't get cold enough often means they simply don't produce.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get them at a garden-shop or a nursery that grew them ? If they were grown there they are fine . Are you in mountains where elevation is going to make a big temperature difference? For one plant,I would plant it and see what happens. Some information is not perfect: I just gave up on my Ein Shimer ( ?) apple that is supposed to grow in zone 8 ,but doesn't make fruit.

Comment: Got it at a garden shop that sources from many big growers such as Dave Wilson Nursery and Monrovia. California is very hilly, but I am personally not on a hill. In fact, I live near sea level right next to the bay. The water makes everything more temperate (colder during day, hotter at night).